# C - pass predefined function as pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am working with a Hashtable struct that maps keys to values, where the values are (void *) so that Hashtables can hold any kind of value.

To be able to free those values, the deconstructor of a Hashtable takes in a pointer to a freeing function as an argument. In my case, I know I am going to be freeing basic types, like char* and int*. Is it possible to pass in a pointer to the free() function, since this can deal with basic types?

Something like this:

```
FreeHashTable(hashtable_name, free);
```

Comment: What is the problem you have encountered as you have tried this?

Comment: It doesnt seem to produce any compiler errors, and I think it's working, but I wanted to confirm that this is the way you would pass the free function into FreeHashTable. In other words, the call doesnt expect a locally-defined variable free, does it?

Comment: Well, how could I know ... *you* are designing the code, so you only you know what your code expects! If you make the second argument a `void(*)(void*)`, then you can pass any function pointer to `FreeHashTable`, including `free`, and this does indeed look like a decent approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) pass to `free` every pointer that has returned by `malloc`, no matter which type (or struct) it points to. Be careful to **not** pass to `free` pointers that you didn't get from malloc. (Middle of arrays, local variables, etc)

BTW, unless some of your data types need some work before freeing, you can do it without pass pointer to function - just call `free`.

Comment: This program is for a class, and in this case, I am expected to provide a pointer to the function that will free the type. I am certain that every type came from a malloc too, so is my line above correct? Is that the way I should pass in the function pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the pointer to the function.

Just loop through the values and call `free`.

Comment: I normally would do that, but in this case I must call this function that gives the hashtable to be freed and the function for how to free each individual payload. Another module does the work of the looping, which I cannot change.